# Find a word NOT preceded by a specific symbol and do NOT highlight anything before this word

Tags: regex

This task is driving me nuts.

I need to find all words `IsPlayerRcon`, but not `!IsPlayerRcon` and highlight ONLY `IsPlayerRcon` without highlighting any preceding symbol.

The thing is, if I JUST search for `IsPlayerRcon`, it obviously highlights all matches, including this word after `!`, that I don't want.

And if I search for `[^!]IsPlayerRcon`, it actually does what I want, but it highlights all matches like this: `(IsPlayerRcon`, so it includes any other symbols before `IsPlayerRcon` except `!`.

What do I want is to make the regex which would highlight ONLY `IsPlayerRcon` not preceded by `!` and would NOT highlight anything before `IsPlayerRcon`.

I use Notepad++.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind, that'd work since it just looks behind without capturing. Here's a tutorial http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: A bit of googling examples of negative lookbehind, and I was able to do this. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve this yourself, please considering adding an answer with what you ended up doing and why it works and accepting it. That would help users who run into the same issue in the future.

Comment: Will do as soon as the website allows me.

Comment: Regular expressions do not "highlight". There is no syntax for highlight this and don't highlight that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(?<=[^!])IsPlayerRcon
```

Comment: (?<!!)IsPlayerRcon worked for me, but this works too, thanks.